# Where I can find a desktop manager for Blackberries?

Tags: linux, backup, blackberry

I'm scrapping an old BlackBerry but I need to dump all the information in the phone somewhere and upload it to a new one, so I need an application that:

1. *Must* work in Linux
2. Do full backups and restore of all the data.
3. Synchronize between cellphones
4. Can upgrade the OS (optional)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There aren't too many options to pick from but [Barry](http://www.netdirect.ca/software/packages/barry) will cover you for most of it:

- Does full and partial backup of all the databases on the Blackberry, including configurations
- Does full and partial restore of all of the databases
- Allows you to synchronize several phones
- Works on GNU/Linux and BSD
- Licensed under LGPL/GPL
- Allows you to use your phone as modem (tethering)

One thing it doesn't do, however, is allow you to upgrade the phone.

I used it and the only failure I found is that it can't backup non-ASCII entries since it uses other low-level system, but Barry is working on it. This is an active project that uses C++.

There are packages for most major distributions of Linux (deb and RPM) ready to use.